# Active Directory - Test users and groups

Tags: testing, active-directory, test-data

I am wanting to test a tool which synchronises with Active Directory.  I want a decent number of users and groups to give the utility a reasonably rigorous test.  Does any know a way of populating AD with fake users and groups?

Comment: This is a programming stack Exchange, for a better audience, you'd better post your question to serverfault.

Comment: Fair comment. The purpose of this is to test some code that I am writing.

Answer (score 3):

It exists numbers of tools,

Citix provide : [Active Directory User Creation Utility – Free Download and Source Code](http://blogs.citrix.com/2010/07/09/active-directory-user-creation-utility-free-download-and-source-code/)